# connecting to database through network using java application

Tags: java

hey guys can you please help me again, i want my restaurant system to connect to database through network i.e. when waiter place order using handheld computer(PDA) and sending it to chef, so i want all data to be saved in database via network. i'm using java for this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lovely [Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) on that.  Easy way is to use JDBC.